# Playing sounds only for specified player entities

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

I'm making a game mode for Garry's Mod, and I'm trying to write a system in which I play sounds only for certain players.

The problem I'm running across is that doing so from server-side would take a lot of bandwidth, but I'm not sure how I could reliably do it from the client side.

None of the Garry's Mod sound functions seem to take player entity arguments, and `surface.playsound` would resort back to the method of server telling the client what sounds to play for every sound played.

Answer (score 1):

Only took 5 years, but to answer your question:

```
hook.Add("PlayerDeathSound", "DeFlatline", function() return true end) 
local noise = Sound("death.wav") 
hook.Add("PlayerDeath", "NewSound", function(vic,unused1,unused2) vic:EmitSound(noise) end)
```

Here is a link to a video tutorial: https://youtu.be/UPtKeJmLmoA